# How to sort by first name alphabetically and by last name

Tags: java, appium

I have 3 elements and they have first  names and  last names its a button. I need to check if they sorted by first name and then by last name by alphabetically.Page object for elements is ListV_Sorted. I think I just sorted by first name elements. 0 element = Jack Daniels, 1 element = John Fera, 2 element = Mike Durov. ListV is a page object for the elements. I get an error It says expected true but found false.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void sortingOrder() {

    Log.log(driver).info("About to Alphebetically Sort");
    List<MobileElement> products_MobileElements = new LinkedList<MobileElement>();
    products_MobileElements = (List<MobileElement>) TicketPassesNames;
    LinkedList<String> product_names =  new LinkedList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<products_MobileElements.size();i++){

        String s = products_MobileElements.get(i).getAttribute("checked");
        String[] tokens = s.split("");
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        if(tokens.length > 0) {
            firstName = tokens[0];
            lastName = tokens[tokens.length -1];
            product_names.add(s);
            product_names.add(firstName);
            product_names.add(lastName);
        }
    }
    boolean result = checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names);

    Assert.assertEquals(checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names), true);
    Log.log(driver).info("Tickest Passes names are in alphabetical order.");
    System.out.println(result);
}

//Method takes a String to Sort AlphabeticalLy
public static boolean checkAlphabeticalOrder(LinkedList<String> product_names){

    String previous = ""; // empty string

    for (final String current: product_names) {
        if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
            return false;
        previous = current;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `split("");` will split the String into single characters. So product_names.get(0) will be "Jack Daniels", product_names.get(1) = "J" and product_names.get(2) = "s". I don't think that is what you intend to do. I also don't really get what you intend with that whole splitting + adding 3 values into the list for each name anyway. I think you need to rethink your whole approach and probably use the opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: element basically a string = "Jack Daniels" I was trying to split two words. How would you do it.

Comment: Splitting by space instead of an empty string would be a start. But again: I still don't understand why you want to split at all. Why not just compare the strings as they are?

Comment: How would you do it? I'm little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `java.util.LinkedList` you should be using a `java.util.TreeSet` to sort the input using a data structure.

I have create a slightly changed version of your code which prints "true" after the program execution. The main difference though is the usage of the `java.util.TreeSet` and of the `Collection` interface.

Here is the changed version:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SimpleTests2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        sortingOrder();
    }

    //Method takes a String to Sort AlphabeticalLy
    public static boolean checkAlphabeticalOrder(Collection<String> product_names) {

        String previous = ""; // empty string

        for (final String current : product_names) {
            if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
                return false;
            previous = current;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void sortingOrder() {

//        Log.log(driver).info("About to Alphebetically Sort");
        List<MobileElement> products_MobileElements;
        products_MobileElements = Arrays.asList(
                new MobileElement("Mike Durov"), new MobileElement("Jack Daniels"), new MobileElement("John Fera"));
        // Here is the main change to your code!
        Collection<String> product_names = new TreeSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < products_MobileElements.size(); i++) {

            String s = products_MobileElements.get(i).getAttribute("checked");
            String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
            String firstName = "";
            String lastName = "";
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                firstName = tokens[0];
                lastName = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
                product_names.add(s);
                product_names.add(firstName);
                product_names.add(lastName);
            }
        }
        boolean result = checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names);

//        Assert.assertEquals(checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names), true);
//        Log.log(driver).info("Tickest Passes names are in alphabetical order.");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(product_names);
    }


    private static class MobileElement {

        private String name;

        public MobileElement(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAttribute(String checked) {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot how come result prints out  false, false, false.